# why do we add offset to generate gcode for 3d printer in following code?

Tags: c++, g-code

```
// offset of the emitted Gcode coordinates to the .stl ones
Vertex offset={75,75,get("z_offset")-min_z};

Vertex position={0,0,0};
for(int i=0; i<layers.size(); i++){
    Layer& l=layers[i];
    fprintf(file, "G92 E0\n");                        // reset extrusion axis

    float feedrate=(i==0) ? 500.f : 1800.f ;
    fprintf(file, "G1 Z%f F%f\n",l.z+offset.z,feedrate); // move to layer's z plane
```

Here an offset is added to gcode.what is the need for this?

Answer (score 0):

The offset <sup>1</sup>apparently makes the printed z-values relative to `min_z`.

The comment `move to layer's z plane` is also a possible answer.

You just have to define `layer's z plane`.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>) Disclaimer: too little context has been provided to be sure of anything. For a code review consider [some other site in this family](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is for more clear programming questions.</sup>